# Submit a JQuery form with Enter key press

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've tried various solutions, but none are suitable for my particular case!
How can I make it so that when the user presses 'Enter' the form submits & searches.

I am using rotten tomatoes API with AJAX by the way.

**FORM**

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET"><h3 class="white">Search for a movie here!:</h3><br> 
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="">&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Go!" onClick="filmlist(this.form)">
</form>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function filmlist(form) {
    $('#films table').empty(); //removes previous search results before adding the new ones.
    var apikey = "APIKEY";
    var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";
    var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;
    var query = form.inputbox.value; //uses the value from the input box as the query search
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // sends the query
        $.ajax({
            url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: searchCallback
        });
    });
    // receives the results
    function searchCallback(data) {
        $('#films table').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query);
        var movies = data.movies;
        $.each(movies, function (index, movie) {
            $('#films table').append('<tr><td width="70" rowspan="2"><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
                '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '."><img class="ajaximage" src="' + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" /></a></td><td class="ajaxfilmlisttitle"><h3><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
                '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '.">' + movie.title + '</a></h3>Release year: ' + movie.year + '</td></tr><tr><td class="ajaxfilmlistinfo">Audience Score: ' + movie.ratings.audience_score +
                '<br>' + 'Cinema Release Date: ' + movie.release_dates.theater +
                '<br>Runtime: ' + movie.runtime + ' minutes</td></tr>');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll give it a go, a more complete solution for the whole 'Listen to Keypress Enter to submit' which I faced some problems while making it work cross-browser, perhaps this will do it for you.

According to your code, this should work just fine.

```
  $('#inputbox').live("keypress", function(e) {
     var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
     if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
     }
  });
```

Comment: Just a note: jquery has deprecated the live method and replace it with on.

Answer (score 4):

If the user presses enter on any `form` element, the `submit` action will be called. You can listen for that event via `.submit`:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // stop the actual submit
  // ajax code goes here to submit data
});
```

Comment: Hey, is the code that should go inside the function the 'filmlist(this.form)' part of the following:

<input type="button" id="button" value="Go!" onClick="filmlist(this.form)">

Comment: Pretty much, yes. However, remove the document.ready and be familiar with tips Satpal made

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's better not to use it inline, but its the only way it seems to work.
I have removed the document ready & the functionality hasn't been affected, but changed the type to submit was ineffective.

Comment: The code you wrap inside of `document.ready` is code that needs to wait until the document is ready. Using inside a function like this won't do anything. You need to wrap the code above in document.ready so that is starts listening for the submit event when the HTML elements have all loaded. Otherwise, `#myForm` won't exist yet

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery, I use this short snippet for capturing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press events, and binding a function to it (without actually resorting to forms and submitting):

```
$.fn.pressEnter = function(fn) {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).off('enterPress');
    $(this).on('enterPress', fn);
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterPress");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Next, call the `.pressEnter` jQuery extension on your element(s):

```
$('mySelector').pressEnter(function () {
  console.log('Enter pressed!');
});
```